# About operator[] of vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, operator-keyword

I was under the assumption that one could use the `operator[]` for any `vector`, irrespective of the type of the data it contained. I wrote this algorithm to remove white spaces from a string, where each string is indexed from a vector of strings using the `operator[]`.

```
std::vector<string> substrs;
//after reading strings into the vector
//by means of user input
for(auto i : substrs){
    string s = substrs[i];
    s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
}
```

The above code segment doesn't compile due to the following error:

> error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'vector' (aka
>   'vector, allocator > >')
>   string s = substrs[i];

Can anyone explain?

Comment: You are using a range based for loop. What you have in i is the strings in your vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're indexing using the wrong type. You're indexing with a string.

```
for(auto i: substrs) {  ... }
```

`auto` there is a `std::string` type, not an arithmetic type. You cannot index a vector by string.

Try using `for (size_t i = 0; i < substrs.size(); ++i) { ... }` if you need an index, or use C++'s auto-ranges.

**Edit** As noted by Code-Apprentice, what you likely want is:

```
for (auto& str: substrs) { ... }
```

Comment: Note that for the use-case in the OP, `for (auto& s : substrs)` is probably the most appropriate loop.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to index here at all. As other's have stated, the loop variable is the element of the vector (an `std::string`). If you use `auto&`, then you can manipulate the members of the `vector` directly:

```
std::vector<string> substrs;

for(auto& s : substrs){
    s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that the "modern" for loop iterates through the values of the std::vector (it works with any collection). It does not iterate through the indexes to the elements of the vector.

You have to be careful, though. `for(auto s:substr)` will create (and put into s) a copy of each of the strings. If you modify this copy, you do not modify the actual string inside the collection. What you need is to create a reference to each string inside the vector. See this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> a { "a", "b"};

    for (auto s: a) {
        s = "x";
    } 

    for (auto s: a) {
        std::cout << "element: " << s << std::endl;
    } 

    for (auto &s: a) {
        s = "x";
    } 

    for (auto s: a) {
        std::cout << "element: " << s << std::endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

which will output:

```
element: a
element: b
element: x
element: x
```

So what you need to solve your problem is:

```
for(auto &s: substrs){
   s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using a range-based `for`, the control variable takes on the type of the items in the collection you're iterating over, not (as you seem to think) a numeric index into the collection.

In fact, there's no need to use an index at all since the range-based `for` gives you *direct* access to each item in the collection - just modify it as you see fit.

The following complete program shows how you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    // Create a test vector.

    std::vector<std::string> stringVec;
    stringVec.push_back("Hello, my name is pax");
    stringVec.push_back("My hovercraft is full of eels");

    // Output the initial items (with spaces).

    for (const auto &str: stringVec)
        std::cout << '[' << str << ']' << std::endl;

    // Remove spaces from each item.

    for (auto &str: stringVec)
        str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());

    // Output the final items (no spaces any more).

    for (const auto &str: stringVec)
        std::cout << '[' << str << ']' << std::endl;
}
```

The output is, as expected:

```
[Hello, my name is pax]
[My hovercraft is full of eels]
[Hello,mynameispax]
[Myhovercraftisfullofeels]
```